# Custom iterable class Issue

Tags: apex, batch

I have written a batch class with Iterable interface  and the custom itrable is below.
My question is i am comparing the value of i in the code to 8 if the records are more than 8 it throws CPU Time exceeds. so to run the batch i need to check the limit of records and edit accordingly. will there be any other solution ? cz everytime i cannot check the number of records to be processed what if there are more than 50000 records ?

```
global class CustomIterable implements Iterator<Account> {
    List<Account> accs {get; set;}
    Integer i {get; set;}
    global CustomIterable () {
        accs = [SELECT Id, Name, NumberOfEmployees FROM Account WHERE Name = 'false'];
    }

    global boolean hasNext() {
        if(i >= accs.size()) {
            system.debug('no next');
            return false; 
        }
        else {
            system.debug('yes next');
            return true;
        }
    } 

    global Account next() {
        // 8 is an arbitrary // constant in this example // that represents the // maximum size of the list.
        if(i == 8){
            return null;
        }
        i++; 
        system.debug('i is now ' + i);
        return accs[i-1]; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: can you post the batch class code?

Answer (score 0):

**Consideration of Iterable Interface in Batch Apex :-**

- If you use an iterable, the governor limit for the total number of
  records retrieved by SOQL queries is still enforced.
- If your code accesses external objects and is used in batch Apex, use
  Iterable instead of Database.QueryLocator.

**Try Below Code:**

```
global class CustomIterable implements Iterable<AggregateResult> {
   global Iterator<AggregateResult> Iterator(){
      return new CustomIterator();
   }
}
```

---

```
    global class CustomIterator implements Iterator<AggregateResult> {
    AggregateResult [] results {get;set;}
    // tracks which result item is returned
    Integer index {get; set;} 

    global CustomIterator() {
        index = 0;

            // Fire query here to load the results
            String query = 'SELECT Name,OwnerId ownerId NumberOfEmployees FROM Account WHERE Name = \'false\' Group By OwnerId'; 
            if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                query = 'SELECT Name,OwnerId ownerId NumberOfEmployees FROM Account WHERE Name = \'false\' Group By OwnerId limit 1'; 
            }
            results = Database.query(query);


    } 

    global boolean hasNext(){ 
        system.debug('Result size:'+results.size());
        return results != null && !results.isEmpty() && index < results.size(); 
    }    

    global AggregateResult next(){        
        return results[index++];            
    }       
}
```

---

**The Design your batch class:**

```
global class AccountNotificationBatch implements Database.Batchable<AggregateResult>,Database.Stateful {

        global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;
        global Iterable<AggregateResult> start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
        {
            return new CustomIterable(); 
        }
        global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
            //Add your loic here
            Id actorId = (Id)scope[0].get('ownerId');
            Map<Id,Account> acountMap = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id,Name froM Account where OwnerId =:actorId]);
            if(Test.isRunningTest()){
                acountMap = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id,Name froM Account where OwnerId =:actorId limit 1]);
            }
    // Add your logic here
        }   



        global void finish(Database.BatchableContext info) {

        } 
    }
```

Try the above code and let me know if it helps.

Comment: I have to write simlar batch for contentDocumentLink which is not supported using Database.queryLocator that why i want to use iterable batch for it but worried about limits how do i take care

Comment: Hi guys can you pls confirm that SOQL limit will be 50k only for below statement of yours . "If you use an iterable, the governor limit for the total number of records retrieved by SOQL queries is still enforced." Hoping it cannot be 50 million as per batch's total limit while using a iterator with it.